# Unable to register node on selenium grid

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

Unable to install selenium node on grid.
Grid console is accessible and there is no issue related to firewall or port blocking.

```
java -jar selenium-server-4.14.0.jar node --version
node version: 4.14.0, revision: e5a96349ce
```

Can someone please help with the correct command. I am getting below message after executing command:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/path/chromedriver -jar selenium-server-4.14.0.jar -role node -hub http://<hub_ip>:<hub_port>/grid/register -port 5555 -browser "browserName=chrome,maxInstances=5"
Selenium Server commands

A list of all the commands available. To use one, run `java -jar selenium.jar
commandName`.

  completion    Generate shell autocompletions
  distributor   Adds this server as the distributor in a selenium grid.
  hub           A grid hub, composed of sessions, distributor, and router.
  info          Prints information for commands and topics.
  node          Adds this server as a Node in the Selenium Grid.
  router        Creates a router to front the selenium grid.
  sessionqueue  Adds this server as the new session queue in a selenium grid.
  sessions      Adds this server as the session map in a selenium grid.
  standalone    The selenium server, running everything in-process.

For each command, run with `--help` for command-specific help

Use the `--ext` flag before the command name to specify an additional classpath
to use with the server (for example, to provide additional commands, or to
provide additional driver implementations). For example:

  java -jar selenium.jar --ext example.jar:dir standalone --port 1234
```

Tried installing previous selenium gris versions but same issue is occuring